# Devise throwing sign in/sign up error following registration attempt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, cancan

I'm developing a Rails application which uses [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) + [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) to handle authentication + authorization. My application recently decided to start throwing an error and redirecting to the login page following an attempted registration. This behavior appears to originate from Devise. The error is: `You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.`

I've tried to backtrack since the error began showing up after I previously did not have issues, but I can't seem to find where the issue started.

**models/ability.rb:**

```
 1 class Ability
 2   include CanCan::Ability
 3
 4   def initialize(user)
 5     user ||= User.new
 6     if user.role? :admin
 7       can :manage, :all
 8     else
 9       can [:create, :new], User
10       can [:read, :update, :destroy], User do |u|
11         u.id == user.id
12       end
13   end
14 end
```

**models/user.rb**

```
 1 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 3   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
 4          :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
 5
 6   ROLES = %w[admin free basic intermediate corporate]
 7
 8   def role?(role)
 9     self.role == role.to_s
10   end
11 end
```

**controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb**

```
 1 class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
 2   before_action :configure_permitted_parameters
 3
 4   def index
 5     @users = User.all
 6   end
 7
 8   protected
 9   def configure_permitted_parameters
10     devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) {
11       |u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
12     devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {
13       |u| u.permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :phone, :password, :password_confirmation) }
14   end
15 end
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
 1 ExampleCom::Application.routes.draw do
 2   devise_scope :user do
 3     get 'login' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
 4     post 'login' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
 5     delete 'logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
 6
 7     get 'register' => 'devise/registrations#new', :as => :new_user_registration
 8
 9     get 'profile' => 'devise/registrations#edit', :as => :edit_user_registration_path
10
11     get 'users' => 'users/registrations#index'
12   end
13   devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions], controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations' }
14 end
```

**rake routes**

```
                     Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
                    root GET    /                              application#index
                   about GET    /about(.:format)               application#about
           docs_overview GET    /docs/overview(.:format)       application#docs_overview
           docs_libs_php GET    /docs/libs/php(.:format)       application#docs_libs_php
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
```

Comment: You have no idea what your last changes are?  Perhaps your strong parameters are incomplete. You could test this by changing the following to the sign_up params: u.permit!

Comment: @rails4guides.com I appreciate the suggestion, but tried it and no luck. Also, the error being returned from the server is a `401` with a generic forbidden error that doesn't match what I was seeing when the strong parameters weren't properly setup.